# Generate series of multiplied numbers but starting with 1

Tags: excel

I am trying to generate an array of integers of the general form

```
n*0
n*1
n*2
n*3
```

BUT the first number needs to be a one (1), not a zero.

This formula works:

```
=IF((ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))-1)*n=0,1,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))-1)*n)
```

but I'm hoping there is a more efficient method, using worksheet functions.

Comment: n is the interval? What do you mean by `more efficient method`?

Comment: Fewer functions, shorter formula. If n=99, then series 1,99,198,297,...

Comment: Well you don't need `INDIRECT` in there. `=IF((ROW($A$1:$A$10)-1)*n=0,1,(ROW($A$1:$A$10)-1)*n)` should work fine. But I'll check if there's anything more.

Comment: I was hoping for a different algorithm. I'd  like to be able to control the upper limit. It won't  always be 10x

Comment: That would depend where the size of your array is dependent? or which or what controls the upper limit. If the size changes then that explains the use of `INDIRECT` where you can concatenate a number from another cell or source which dictates the size of your array.

Comment: @L42 I also don't like using ROW to generate the series since it will change if rows are inserted or deleted in the referenced range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use: `=ABS(seq-0.5)+0.5`

where `Seq = {0,1,...,m}*n`

If you want to create a large fixed array for `Seq`, you can enter from the immediate window:

```
Names.Add "Seq",[(row(1:100)-1)*99]
```

see also http://www.chandoo.org/forum/threads/create-an-array-of-numbers.13433/.

Comment: Thank you both for your contribution and the link to the chandoo website.  I tested your version for speed, compared with my version using *=IF((seq-1)...* and find that my version is very slightly faster, when generating an array of 10^6 numbers.

Comment: But I don't think the difference is significant.  Your second example is intriguing.

Comment: i may have made an error but in trying to replicate your findings by array-entering and filling `=SUM(IF(99*(Seq-1)=0,1,99*(Seq-1)))` vs `=SUM(ABS(99*(Seq-1)-0.5)+0.5)` i find the latter quicker. That's with either of the INDEX or INDIRECT definitions for `seq`. With a fixed range it may well be quicker to use your `IF` version - which definition were you basing results on?

Comment: I did  the test entirely differently.  Clear a worksheet. Set calculation to manual. Enter either =ABS((SEQ-1)*99-0.5)+0.5  or   =IF((seq-1)*99=0,1,(seq-1)*99)  with seq defined as =ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1000000,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1000000,1000000,1)).  Start HiResTimer; Calculate worksheet; Stop HiResTimer; record elapsed time.  Average time over 20 repetitions is about 0.00021 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there isn't a more efficient algorithm than generating the series starting with zero, and testing for zero, substituting one.

However, the series can be generated more efficiently, and I believe in a non-volatile manner by using a technique I first saw posted years ago by Harlan Grove, if there is no need to specify the upper bound.

Define a name:

```
seq  Refers to: =ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65536,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65536,10,1))
```

where the 10 refers to the number in the sequence, and any value could be substituted

My formula would then become, with n=99

```
=IF((seq-1)*99=0,1,(seq-1)*99)
```

which would generate the array:

```
{1;99;198;297;396;495;594;693;792;891}
```

Thanks all.

**EDIT**
Doing some timing tests shows that the **seq** method runs significantly (3x) faster than does the **row(indirect ...** method when generating an array of 10^6 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Place a value in **A1,** say 99.  In another cell enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)=1,1,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*$A$1)
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]

Comment: That may be OK for generating the series in a range of cells, but not as an array in a formula as does my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the `IF` function by using `MAX`:

[image]

If you want to be able to start in any cell, use this formula:

```
=MAX(1,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*$A$1)
```

You can also avoid the `IF` function within the array formula, taking advantage of the fact that TRUE equals 1:

```
=(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))-1)*99+(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))-1=0)
```

I've tested both our methods, by entering them into cells A1:A1048576 (as an array formula).  My method runs a little over twice as fast as yours.

Comment: That may be OK for generating the series in a range of cells, but not as an array in a formula as does my example

Comment: How did you time?  I timed some examples by: Set sheet calculation to manual.  Clear the sheet.  Enter the formula into A1 having it generate 10^6 numbers.  Timed the process using the HiRes timer.  I found little difference between yours and my initial effort.

Comment: I did the same timing method using the **seq** method in my answer, and found that method to execute significantly (3x) faster than either of our row(indirect(  algorithms; but no real difference between the "IF" method and the "TRUE" method

Comment: Hmm, I assume you entered it as a separate array formula in each cell (instead of doing the entire range as the array formula)? If I do this in Excel 2010, then do Ctrl+Alt+F9 to recalculate, mine runs about twice as fast as your original formula.  Anyway, I'm glad you've found a better solution.

Comment: I did it both ways -- array & normal. The array ran slower but the relation between the methods persisted. I ensured there was only one formula at a time on the sheet because of the volatility issue.